# Reset new keys to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a python dictionary.

```
A=[0:'dog',1:'cat',3:'fly',4,'fish',6:'lizard']
```

I want to reset the keys according to `range(len(A))`(the natural increment), which should look like:

```
new_A=[0:'dog',1:'cat',2:'fly',3:'fish',4:'lizard']
```

How could I do that?

Comment: a dictionary uses curly braces not square ones

Comment: @vaultah But that will not preserve the relative order of the values, will it?

Comment: A dict with keys 0-4 may as well just be a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working example for both py2.x and py3.x:

```
A = {0: 'dog', 1: 'cat', 3: 'fly', 4: 'fish', 6: 'lizard'}

B = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(A.values())}
print(B)
```

Comment: @vaultah The order of A.values() is quasi-random and just because you get `{0:'dog',1:'cat',2:'fly',3:'fish',4:'lizard'}` once you cannot assume that it always is that order - that is what I meant with correctly. I was thinking that deterministic ordering would be important.

Comment: @janbrohl I don't know what you're talking about, read first what the question is asking

Comment: when completely reading the question you see that the result should look like `{0:'dog',1:'cat',2:'fly',3:'fish',4:'lizard'}` which happens to keep the same sorting order for the keys.

Comment: janbrohl is right, python dicts to not force a specific order. On pypy dicts are ordered by default so it will break when the items are not inserted in "the right order".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign new keys in the ascending order of old keys, then

```
new_A = {i: A[k] for i, k in enumerate(sorted(A.keys()))}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same order of keys

```
A={0:'dog',1:'cat',3:'fly',4,'fish',6:'lizard'}
new_A=dict((i,A[k]) for i,k in enumerate(sorted(A.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not ordered. If your keys are incremental integers, you might as well use a list.

new_A = list(A.values())

Answer (score 0):

If you want ordering by creation as well as access by key, then you want an `OrderedDict`.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> d['Cat'] = 'cool'
>>> d['Dog'] = 'best'
>>> d['Fish'] = 'cold'
>>> d['Norwegian Blue'] = 'ex-parrot'
>>> d
OrderedDict([('Cat', 'cool'), ('Dog', 'best'), ('Fish', 'cold'), ('Norwegian Blue', 'ex-parrot')])
 >>> d.values()
odict_values(['cool', 'best', 'cold', 'ex-parrot'])
>>> d.keys()
odict_keys(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Norwegian Blue'])
```

You retain the ability to access the items as a sequence in the order that they were added, but you also have the fast access-by-key which a dict (hash) gives you. If you want "natural" sequence numbers you use `enumerate` as normal:

```
>>> for i,it in enumerate( d.items()): 
...   print( '%5d %15s %15s' % ( i,it[0], it[1]) )
... 
    0             Cat            cool
    1             Dog            best
    2            Fish            cold
    3  Norwegian Blue       ex-parrot
>>>
```